# Using reference transaction with Paypal Standard

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I want to use reference transactions using Paypal. I am using Paypal Standard. But I didn't find any documentation of Paypal using Paypal standard. But found using express checkout. Moreover in reference transaction documentation, there was given the requirement for creating billing agreement between customer and merchant.

So is there any way of using reference transactions purely using Paypal Standard without using any other method in any of the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference Transactions can be performed only via API's.So,it is not possible to do Reference Transaction in PayPal Payment Standard. It is a part of the Express Checkout flow.